# How to get nth-of-type patterns to work like 1-2-2-1?

Tags: css

Trying to get nth-of-type to style elements with this pattern: 1-2-2-1.

For example, it needs to look like this:

blue red

red blue

blue red

red blue

blue red

red blue

I have a lot of links set in 1 container, I am trying to get it to be in 2 columns and to be designed in alternating colors (like shown in the red-blue list here).

I tried messing around with nth-of-type, but couldn't figure it out, for now, I am using something like this:

```
.post-link:nth-of-type(2) {code...}
.post-link:nth-of-type(3) {code...}
.post-link:nth-of-type(6) {code...}
.post-link:nth-of-type(7) {code...}
.post-link:nth-of-type(10) {code...}
.post-link:nth-of-type(11) {code...}
```

But this manual approach only takes me so far, links are being added to the page all the time and I need it to work without setting a specific rule for each box.

I tried something like this with no success as well:

```
.post-link {background: #3c6d84;}
.post-link:nth-of-type(2n) {background: #fe7625;}
.post-link:nth-of-type(3n) {background: #fe7625;}
```

Trying to get the right pattern as mentioned above.

Comment: So you simply want elements matching `4n+2` and `4n+3` to be red …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like

```
.post-link::not(:nth-child(4n + 1)):not(:nth-child(4n + 4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly! Can you please explain this? I would love to understand it better, thanks.